# Minus positive with negative value in a table using subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the data below:

```
| Amount | Type | Employee |
| -----  | ---- | -------- |
| 500   |  A   |  001     |
| 200   |  B   |  001     |
| 300   |  A   |  002     |
| 200   |  A   |  002     |
| 100   |  B   |  002     |
```

In the scenario above, all `Type` A columns are positive values, and `Type` B are negative values.

I need to calculate the amount of each employee with positive minus negative as the end result, which means Type A minus Type B.

So Employee 001 should have the result `500 - 200 = 300`, and Employee 002 is `300 + 200 - 100 = 400`.

I have following incomplete query:

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM A WHERE Type = 'A') -  
 (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM A WHERE Type = 'B') As Payable, Employee
FROM Payroll A
WHERE Company = @Company AND Month = @Month AND Year = @Year
GROUP BY Employee
```

In the query above, the statement `SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM A WHERE Type = 'A'` is trying to get the positive Amount of the `Payroll` table which is already filtered by Company, Month and Year column. It didn't work because `A` is not recognize as a valid object.

So what should I do to get the data from the filtered `Payroll` table rather than I have to put in the `WHERE` condition again into both subquery?

EDIT:

Thanks Kannan and Thomas for the suggestion, but I still have problem achieving the desire result. Right now, this is my modified query with `CASE`

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN -Amount ELSE Amount END) As Payable, Employee
FROM Payroll A
WHERE Company = @Company AND Month = @Month AND Year = @Year
GROUP BY Employee
```

And this is the result of the query:

```
| Payable | Employee |
| -----   | -------- |
| 500     |  001     |
| -200    |  001     |
| 500     |  002     |
| -100    |  002     |
```

Instead of sum up the value, both positive and negative is displayed as different rows.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the table name and you have to repeat the conditions and filter for the employee:

```
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payroll WHERE Type = 'A' AND Company = @Company AND Month = @Month AND Year = @Year AND Employee = A.Employee)
```

But you can also use a different approach which doesn't need a subselect at all:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(Amount * CASE WHEN = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) As Payable, Employee
FROM Payroll A
WHERE Company = @Company AND Month = @Month AND Year = @Year
GROUP BY Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

you can query as below:

```
Select Employee, Sum(Case when type = 'B' then -Amount else Amount End) as Sm
   From Payroll 
   WHERE Company = @Company AND Month = @Month AND Year = @Year
   GROUP BY Employee
```